# how to resize popup according to content in openlayers 2

Tags: popup, openlayers

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>SPIA positions</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body,
    #basicMap {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="OpenStreetMaps/OpenLayers.js"></script>
  <script>
    function init() {
      map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");
      var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
      var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); //     Transform from WGS 1984
      var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
      var position1 = new OpenLayers.LonLat(29.856919813673, 30.6698231962015).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);

      //this initial size of the popup appears to be infinite in one dimension

      var popup1 = new OpenLayers.Popup("popup1", position1, new OpenLayers.Size("20121210_5"), "20121210_6", false);
      var position2 = new OpenLayers.LonLat(29.8555655833635, 30.6691027291649).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);
      var popup2 = new OpenLayers.Popup("popup2", position2, new OpenLayers.Size(100, 20), "20121210_7", false);
      var position3 = new OpenLayers.LonLat(29.8536289031314, 30.6680431519365).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);
      var popup3 = new OpenLayers.Popup("popup3", position3, new OpenLayers.Size(50, 20), "20121210_8", false);
      var CenterPosition = new OpenLayers.LonLat(29.8513532832137, 30.6614234181425).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);
      var zoom = 16;
      map.addLayer(mapnik);
      map.setCenter(CenterPosition, zoom);
      var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
      map.addLayer(markers);
      Marker1 = new OpenLayers.Marker(position1);
      Marker1.icon.imageDiv.title = "20121210_6";
      markers.addMarker(Marker1);
      popup1.updatesize;
      map.addPopup(popup1);
      Marker2 = new OpenLayers.Marker(position2);
      Marker2.icon.imageDiv.title = "20121210_7";
      markers.addMarker(Marker2);
      popup2.setContentHTML("20121210_5");
      //popup2.setSize("20121210_5");
      //popup2.autosize =true;
      //popup2.maxSize = new OpenLayers.Size(100,20);
      popup2.maxSize = new OpenLayers.Size(100, 20);
      popup2.setSize(new OpenLayers.Size('20121210_5));
      //popup2.updatesize;
      //popup2.maxSize = new OpenLayers.Size(100,20);
      map.addPopup(popup2); Marker3 = new OpenLayers.Marker(position3); Marker3.icon.imageDiv.title = "20121210_8"; markers.addMarker(Marker3); popup3.autosize = true; popup3.updatesize; map.addPopup(popup3);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="init();">
  <div id="basicMap"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have unclosed string in `popup2.setSize(new OpenLayers.Size('20121210_5));`

Comment: true thanks, but that is not the problem.

Comment: Well you didn't describe your problem at all - what's wrong with your code? Read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's better to wrap text in an html div (and usually some more tags such to assist text layout), for example `popup2.setContentHTML('<div class="ol-popup"><p>' + text + '<\/p><\/div>');` then you can use CSS to style the `.ol-popup` class however you wish and let the popup autoSize to fit the div.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the text worked for me:

```js
var popup2 = new OpenLayers.Popup("popup2",position2,new OpenLayers.Size('<div class="ol-popup"><p>20121210_5<\/p><\/div>'),"20121210_7",false);
```